# Throw exceptions C# advanced

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have code with try and catch.

```
try
{
    // Some code...
}
catch (Exception err)
{
     throw err;
}
```

Is there an advantage in writing such code?

To throw the exception from the *catch* and to write *try* and *catch* instead of getting an error from the line that break.

Comment: If written as is, there is no benefit, only downside of screwing up the StackTrace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only catch an exception if you intend to do something with it. For example, to add extra information to it, log it to a file or something like that, or change the exception:

```
try
{
    //Some Code...
}
catch (WebException err)
{
    throw new LicenseException("This was really bad!", err);
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    err.Data.Add("some-info", 123);

    logFramework.Log(err);

    throw;
}
```

Never ever rethrow the same exception (`throw err`): you lose the call stack when you do that. Instead, just `throw`, which retains the call stack.

Comment: can you please add a `finally{}` in here and I'll upvote

Comment: Finally for what? What purpose would it serve in this sample? @MadMyche Is that part of the question?

Comment: No, but if we as a collective are trying to fix and use best practices, I would throw in some cleanup code

Comment: What is there to clean up? I can add a 100 best practices in this sample code, but it would all be irrelevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

In both options you have to catch the exception on a higher level. The first option (*your* code) gives *you* an opportunity to react to an exception or make additional logs.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes such an approach can be used, but generally it's not recommended.

Also, *if* you need to throw an exception like this, you need to change your code a little bit:

```
    try
     {
        //Some Code...
     }
    catch (Exception err)
     {
         //I'll recommend to remove err here, because if not you'll lose  the full stack trace.
         throw;
     }
```